# cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans' when run using initd

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, init.d

I have the following schema that is used by my activemq broker:-

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         file:////u//amqgod//schema//spring-beans.xsd
         http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
         file:////u//amqgod//schema//activemq.xsd">
```

It runs fine if I launch my application from commandline but fails with the following error when launched via initd mechanism:-

ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 23 in X
    ML document from URL [file:/prod/tools/base/etc/config/activemq/amq_prod_broker_config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; l
    ineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 52; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 23 in XML docu
    ment from URL [file:/prod/tools/base/etc/config/activemq/amq_prod_broker_config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumb
    er: 23; columnNumber: 52; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
            at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:98)
            at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
            at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:143)
            at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
            at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:85)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
            at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:251)
            at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:107)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 23 in XML document from URL

initd is nothing but a configuration to run my script automatically when the linux server is restarted.
Help please?

Answer (score 0):

Your schemas locations are weird : why do you specify the xsd with some file:// ?

Keep the original xsd (coming from spring, apcache,...). Just replace file:// with http:// like this :

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd   
  http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
```

Comment: I keep the local copy of spring and activemq xsds' at those locations. Anyways I don't get this exception when I run the script manually. Can the initd experts comment if a script has access to network during its invocation i.e by the time initd is executed is the network available on the machine?

Answer (score 0):

I am bit late on this. I faced a similar issue. This can be resolved by including the correct dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
   <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
   <version>5.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or can be downloaded from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-all)
For a xsd to be register the XBeanNamespaceHandler , these configuration is already done (**spring.handlers and spring.schemas is present in the META-INF folder of jar**)